# Login to google programmatically with organisation account for cypress end-to-end test

Tags: javascript, google-api, integration-testing, cypress

At my organisation, I am trying to set up end-to-end testing with cypress on a testing environment that simulate the real website with copy of the real data.
I currently have trouble to login on the website since we uses google sign on with our organisation email (name@organisation.com). I cannot access google's login form with cypress google doesn't allow bot to login.

Is there a way to login to google with organisation account programmatically with cypress to get a valid token ?

Comment: I haven't done this, but here's a bit of info I came across https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1380#issuecomment-368663427